# Log JSONObject in java without unnecessary backslashes(\)

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

My code:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyMessage {
  public void initMy(JSONObject json) {
    log.info("Object: "+ json.toString());
  }
}
```

For example json={"request":"hello"}
But the logs will display:

```
Object: {\"request\":\"hello\"}
```

How to output logs without unnecessary slashes?

I try

```
json.toString().replace("\\\"", "\"")
```

Comment: Have you tried using just `json` instead of `json.toString()`. I think it should work. Change the statement to `log.info("Object: "+ json);`

Comment: Yes, i tried. Backslashes are also displayed.

Comment: Are you absotely certain the json is `{"request":"hello"}`? The code works as expected for me

Comment: Hello, thank you. It' s work. That logs were written to a file with backslashes. And i didn't see how it worked for console.